# using imagedatagenerator in Keras to add more training dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, dataset

I have images of cars and my goal is to extend my training dataset, I would like to combine the newly generated images and original images and train a deep neural network based on them to perform a classification task.

**From this blog post:** https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/

***"the Keras ImageDataGenerator class is not an “additive” operation. It’s not taking the original data, randomly transforming it, and then returning both the original data and transformed data."***

What method would you suggest for extending the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Keras **ImageDataGenerator** is not an additive operation as you said, it can still help you if you want to train your model on augmented images. Here's how ImageDataGenerator works: you specify images' directory and augmention parameters, and than on each epoch of training the gererator takes take image and transform it. So, that means that if you have 300 images total, with ImageDataGenerator you'll get 300 different transformed images each epoch.

If it's not the way you are looking for, you can try another thing. Use the OpenCV library to read images and save their copies with some transformation such as zooming, shearing, etc. to a one directory. This way you can make as many images per epoch as you want. And when you'he made them, use ImageDataGenerator without any parameters. One problem here - images always are the same. In the first case images should be different on every epoch.

To save new augmented images you can use:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('asd.png')
image = np.array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
)
for _, _ in zip(data_generator.flow(
    image, 
    save_to_dir=<DIR_NAME>,
    save_prefix=<PREFIX>,
    save_format='png'
), range(N)):
    pass
```

Where *N* is number of augmented images you want to create using 1 base image

Comment: how do you mean by "One problem here - images always are the same"?

Comment: For example, you want to rotate your images. In the second case you can create additional images. So, the final dataset can contain your images, and images rotated by 10, 20 and 30 degrees. In this case your model will learn from images rotated 4 times. In the first case all you need is to specify `rotation=30`. And in this case `ImageDataGenerator` will be creating images rotated at a __random__ angle from 0 to 30 degrees. So, in this case your model will train on images rotated by 11, 29, 8.5, etc. degrees. Every epoch different random angle

Comment: Thank you. Could those generated images be added to the original images and saved in the directory for the training? I have 300 images in one of my classes and 4000 images in other classes, I am trying to balance them.

Comment: Could we use image processing techniques? what is the advantage of using "ImageDataGenerator"? I can easily generate new images from directory images and then save them into the same folder. Then I can use that folder to train my network. What would be the advantage of using ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: Yes, you can. ImageDataGenerator is just something that can make your work easier. If you're comfortable with other technics go ahead